# Convert uiimage to binarydata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

In my app am uploading an image from photo library to UIImageView  .
using this step 
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.9);
am getting an imagedata.

I want to insert this image in to service in binary format .

How can i get binary data for an image.
please help me from this .

Comment: in base64 string in quess???

Answer (score 4):

NSData itself is binary data. You can feed NSData object in binary data.